# What is range of $k$ if $a^2 + 2kab + b^2$ is positive for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

What is range of $k$, if $a^2 + 2kab + b^2$ is positive $\forall$ a,b $\in \mathbb{R}$? 
if k=0 then $a^2+b^2\geq0$  $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ 
if k=1 then $(a+b)^2 \geq0$ $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ 
if k=-1 then $(a-b)^2 \geq0$ $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ 
Can we infer from above 3 cases, $k\in[-1,1]$? If so then how? otherwise, how to find range of $k$?

[Editor's comment: probably "positive" is to be read $\ge0$ here. JL]

Comment: We are looking at the parabola $y=x^2+2kbx+b^2$. Use the discriminant, which you have probably known about for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $a^2+2kab+b^2=(a+kb)^2+(1-k^2)b^2$.
Can you show that this becomes negative if $|k|>1$ and is never negative if $k\in[-1,1]$?

Answer (score 0):

Given $$\displaystyle a^2+2kab+b^2 = b\left[\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2+2k\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+1\right] = b^2\left[\left(\frac{a}{b}+k\right)^2+(1-k^2)\right]\geq 00$$

So we get $$\displaystyle  = b^2\left(\frac{a}{b}+k\right)^2+b^2(1-k^2) = (a+kb)^2+b^2(1-k^2)\geq 0$$

So which is possible when $$1-k^2\geq 0\Rightarrow (k-1)(k+1)\leq 0$$

So we get $$-1\leq k\leq 1\Rightarrow k\in \left[-1,1\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a^{2} + 2kab + b^{2} > 0$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $ab > 0$, then (1) $a,b > 0$ or (2) $a,b < 0$. If (1) holds then $2kab < a^{2}+b^{2}$, so $k < \frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{2ab}$; if (2) holds then $k > \frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{2ab}$.

If $ab = 0$, then $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $ab < 0$, then $2kab < a^{2}+b^{2}$, so $k > \frac{a^{2}+b^{2}}{2ab}$.